Brownian motion runs through a circle
Let $(B_t)$ be standard Brownian motion starting from 0, and $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z} = S^1$ be a canonical projection. I want to calculate the expectation of the stopping time $T$, which is the first "running through the circle" time. More precisely, $$T = \inf\{t \geq 0 : \sup_{[0, t]} B_s - \inf_{[0, t]} B_s \geq 2\pi \}$$
I came up with this problem when I was thinking about the "discrete version problem"; If there are $n$ points circularly and you randomly walk on these points, how long would you spend your time to go through all the points, assuming you can go only to your adjacent point in one step?
Anyway, let's get back to the first problem. Let $-b < 0 < a$  and $T_a, T_{-b}$ be two hitting times. i.e. $$T_x = \inf \{t \geq 0 : B_t = x\}$$
I thought it's essential to  calculate the joint distribution of $(T_a, T_{-b})$ for all the $(a, b)$ which satisfies $a+b=2\pi$.
My first approach was to calculate $P(T_a < x,\quad  T_{-b} > y)$. It's enough to calculate the joint distribution of $\sup_{[0, t]} B_s$ and $\inf_{[0, t]} B_s$, but I don't know how to do that. (Reflection principle seems to be some help, but I couldn't come up with a solution.)
Any help would be appreciated.
